# Odd jobs/Tutoring on a UK Tier 2

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, us-citizens, freelance

I am currently on a Tier 2 Worker's Visa in the UK with a Certificate of Sponsorship from a university as a research fellow. I am basically doing research only, and I miss doing some tutoring and teaching.

What I would like to be able to do is some freelance tutoring on the side, just to keep my pedagogical skills up and make some extra spare cash. I have no idea if I can do this on my visa. Has anyone been in this situation? What kind of small side jobs and gigs can people do on a General Tier 2? I am talking about 1-5 hours a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tier 2 general visa allows holders to

> do a second job in the same sector and at the same level as your main job for up to 20 hours per week

https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general

I think tutoring at the undergraduate and postgraduate level would be in the same sector and same level as your main job. Tutoring at the a-level would be questionable. Just be aware, that while your visa may allow you to work a second job your research fellowship may not allow you to take on outside work. Another approach would be to ask your department for a little bit of teaching. They most likely will not pay you, but it is probably the best in terms of your CV.